# Difference between jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap

I ran into a problem with jQuery selectors when setting up an ajaxnavigation for a site.
The site is based on twitter bootstrap and uses the nav-bar and dropdowns provided by the framework.

I use hashchange events to load new content into `section#main` when a link with `class="ajaLink"` is clicked.

I got stuck as it seemed the event wouldn't bind to the links in the twitter bootstrap dropdown menu. I investigated the JS for the dropdowns but I couldn't see anything that would prevent the event from being bound and triggered.

In frustration I chanegd the selector from

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxLink', function (e) {
    ...
}
```

To

```
$('.ajaxLink').on('click', function (e) {
    ...
}
```

This made the event bind to all the links in the nav-bar and dropdowns, but would leave the links in the dynamically loaded content.

I can't figure out the difference between the two selectors and why I get this behaviour. 
My solution so far is to use both the selectors, but this doesnt feel as a solution as long as I cant tell for sure the event wont bind twice to the same element.

So question is what is the difference between the two selectors used?
How would I rewrite the selector to make sure I bind each `.ajaLink` element only once?

The HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- Minimizing the menu under a button when screen gets too small. -->
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            ...

                        </a>

                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <!-- Choose application. -->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a class="ajaxLink" href="/Blabla">Blabla</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a class="ajaxLink" href="/Yadayada">Yadayada</a></li>
                                ...
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Choose application. -->
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Menu 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a class="ajaxLink" href="/Blabla2">Blabla 2</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a class="ajaxLink" href="/Yadayada2">Yadayada 2</a></li>
                                ...
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-search pull-right" action="/Home/Search" method="post" >
                        <input type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Sök" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" id="search-button ">Search</button>
                    </form>


                  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="log label label-important" style="display:none;" ></div>
    <section id="main" style="opacity: 1; ">

    <div class="row-fluid">   
    <div class="span2">

    </div> 
    <div class="span10">
        <span class="gradientlabel"><a href="#">Artiklar</a></span> 

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed overview-table">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>
                    Art No.
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    16791
                </td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
                    175/70-13 82Q Semperit Ice Grip 2 Dubbat
                </td>
                <td>
                    300
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="ajaxLink" href="/Artiklar/Edit/16791">Edit</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    16792
                </td>
                <td style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
                    195/55-15 85Q Uniroyal Nordic Dubbat
                </td>
                <td>
                    550
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="ajaxLink" href="/Artiklar/Edit/16792">Edit</a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            ...
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript

```
//Add event for all ajaxLink (except for the ones in the bootstrap dropdown)
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxLink', function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.attr('href').length > 2) {
        window.location.hash = "!" + self.attr('href');
    }
    return false;
});

//I dont really know yet, but this is the only way to attach the event to bootstraps dropdown, and also have to close the dropdown programmatically.
$('.ajaxLink').on('click', function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    //if (self.prop('tagName') != 'A') { alert('not a link'); self = self.find('a:first'); }
    if (self.attr('href').length > 2) {
        window.location.hash = "!" + self.attr('href');
    }
    self.closest('.dropdown').removeClass('open');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Shorter but duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/8111171/1478467

Comment: On consideration this isn't really a duplicate. Though that has a nice explanation to the difference between the selectors.Bbut why will `$(document).on('click', '.ajaxLink', function(){..});` not bind to the primarily loaded content, but only to the dynamically loaded? So the difference between the two selectors are cleared, but the second part of the question isnt. My final solution that made me confident in not binding multiple times was the following selector: `$('header,#main').on('click', '.ajaxLinl', function(){..});` A lot of edits on this on my behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `$('.ajaxLink').on('click', function (e) { ... }` **only** binds elements that already exists.

`$(document).on('click', '.ajaxLink', function (e) { ... }` has an delegate and also binds `.ajaxLink` elements that are created dynamically in the future.

If you want an delegate you really should use a **parent** that is closer to the child elements than `document`. The reason being that is saves unnecessary searches in the DOM tree, which gives better performance.

Comment: Thank you, after five seconds of thinking this makes sense. But, still, why doesnt $(document).on('click', '.ajaxLink', function (e) { ... } bind to the existing elements in the nav-bar menu ?

Comment: @P-H Unsure, could be a multiple of different things. Could you possibly create an jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I've got a jsfiddle at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fq6Cy/37/) I added console msgs to show which selector that applies to the link. I hope this will help you :)

Comment: @P-H Does this not work as you want it to? http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/fq6Cy/41/. Seems to work, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Hmmm, that works as expected but it doesnt work for me on the site. This on the other hand works on the site as expected `    $('header, #main').on('click', '.ajaxLink', function (e) {
        console.log('second binder');
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.attr('href').length > 2) {
            window.location.hash = "!" + self.attr('href');
        }
        self.closest('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
        return false;
    }); ` I cant figure out where my problem is with the document.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read from the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/), it seems `$('.ajaxLink')` returns an array of all of the current matching DOM elements, and `on('click')` then gets bound once to each item in that array, whereas `$(document).on(’click')` gets called any time any descendant of the document is clicked, then only gets executed if it matches the filert passed in the `.on()` method.

With that in mind, you could also try the following:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on("click", ".ajaxLink", function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: Yes, this is how I interpreted sqve's answer. But for me this implies that `$(document).on(’click')` would attach to every link in the primarily loaded document and _also_ to the dynamically loaded content. But it will _not_ attach to the links in the primarily loaded content. This is what make me wonder.